# Is there a way to only clone the current branch of codecommit repository when invoking lambda function?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-codecommit

I want to let AWS Lambda to clone specific branch when invoking lambda functions, not to clone entire repository in CodeCommit

Hi all, I am doing a work to use a trigger to invoke AWS Lambda function to scan some code in a CodeCommit Repository. I wonder is there a way to just clone the specific branch using boto3? I tried get_repository and get_branches, but it seems not very suitable.
Has anyone met this kind of demand before and have some best practices?